# HTML forms with PHP mechanics

Tags: php, html

Im trying to understand the mechanics behind what is going on when an HTML form is sent to a PHP script and most importantly what is actually inside $_GET and $_POST. Ill try my best to explain what I dont understand.

My understanding of it so far:
When an HTML form is submitted a HTTP request is made to the sever and the *Value part* of name="value"  pairs inside the HTML form are INSERTED into the super-global PHP array either $_GET or $_POST depending on the method used to send the data. Right?

My questions:

1. if we give an input element: name="test[]" and send it with the post method, then based on the above info, the STRING "test[]" is sent to $_POST. So does $_POST contain a string with the value "test[]" or does it contain and array called test? Are we putting an array within an array?
2. Given an input with name="name", if only the string "name" is sent to the server how does it pick value that the user typed into that field.

Comment: Check headers and requests in browser's developers console.

Comment: *Are we putting an array within an array?* And what's strange about this?

Comment: var_dump($_POST); var_dump($_GET); will tell you what is contained within those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names like `name[]` are expanded to arrays but maybe not as you might expect. If you have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar" />
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="ipsum" />
```

If you check *both* checkboxes. You will get:

```
array(
    "foo" => array("bar", "ipsum")
)
```

If you check only the 2nd one you will get:

```
array(
    "foo" => array("ipsum")
)
```

If you check none you will get:

```
array()
```

(so not even the key `foo` is present).

For text inputs it will just send an empty value like:

```
array(
    "foo" => ""
)
```

But for checkboxes it's different.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't move forward until I understood this. Thank You. It is rather strange though.

Comment: It has to do with how form data is serialized. I'll agree that it's a little strange.

Answer (score 0):

Browser will send all values from form and it'll look like this `name1=val1&name2=val2` (name and values pairs separated by `&`).

Then it'll parse it (you can test it using `parse_str()`) and place in `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays (depends on form method). In this step all `[]` occurences will be expanded to arrays.

And yes, you can put array in array. Also you can put next array into that array :) It's called `multidimensional array`.